ASP.NET Core - App Service multiple identity providers, how to configure Program.cs?
I have an ASP.NET Core MVC app deployed to Azure App Service. The authentication is configured as this:

The "Microsoft" Identity provider is a Microsoft Entra External ID for Customer tenant; the "msb2b" is a Microsoft Entra B2B tenant, configured as an OpenID Connect provider. We configured it this way so we could support both email/password logging in and SSO, App Service won't allow us to add more than one provider from Microsoft.
I made my Program.cs to be like this:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(AppServicesAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAppServicesAuthentication();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseCors();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

I deployed this app to Azure App Service. When I visited https://<my-test-app>.azurewebsites.net/, I was redirected to the Microsoft Entra External ID for Customer, logged in, and successfully navigated back to the home page of my app, with all the correct user information.
Then I visited https://<my-test-app>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/msb2b to use Microsoft Entra B2B to login, I put in a credential from a different organization, successfully logged in, but the app shows: "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

The B2B tenant was created by following the instructions here.
The error message was not very clear to me - is there something wrong with my app's code? Or is there something wrong with my tenant's registration? Where can I find more information about this error?

Can you please share the GitHub repo if Possible?

This ended up being an issue with my App Service Authentication configuration.
I added some logs in my app. When "You do not have permission to view this directory or page" shows up, there wasn't any logs, therefore I reached the conclusion that this was an issue with my App Service Authentication configuration.
Sure enough, I changed my B2B tenant to use the Microsoft Entra option and my B2C tenant to use the OpenID connect option, the issue was resolved.
